# Git Clone - Download the repository without keeping git

Tags: git, github, npm, github-cli

I want to bring a couple of plugins into WP and make a script that just fetches them from github within an NPM script.

```
"installplugins": "cd ../../ && 
rm -r mu-plugins && mkdir mu-plugins && 
gh repo clone repo1 mu-plugins && 
gh repo clone repo2 mu-plugins && 
gh repo clone repo3 mu-plugins && 
gh repo clone repo4 mu-plugins && 
gh repo clone repo5 mu-plugins && 
gh repo clone repo6 mu-plugins"
```

Thing is, right at the second git repo clone, it breaks because you the mu-plugins folder is not empty anymore.

Really, at the end of the day I only need to export the git repo and put it in the folder, without keeping all the git bells and whistles, but I cant seem to find the combination of flags needed to do a repo download instead of a classic repo clone.

Anybody can help me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would clone them in their own folder.

```
gh repo clone repo1 mu-plugins/repo1
gh repo clone repo1 mu-plugins/repo2
gh repo clone repo1 mu-plugins/repo3
```

But if you need all the repo files in `mu-plugins`, you would:

- clone those repositories in a separate folder
- go to `mu-plugins` (assuming a `git init .` done in it)
- add the files of each of those repos

That is:

```sh
cd mu-plugins
git work-tree=../aFolder/repo1 add .
git commit -m "Import repo1 content"
...
```

Comment: Yep thats what I ended up doing. They are all in their own repos, and i pull the autoloader first, and at the end I delete is .git folder so it doesn't try to track the changes.